# trigger for invoice number

Tags: sql-server

I'm developing a site in asp.net MVC that should generate invoices.

After some reading regarding the generation of the invoice numbers, my understading is to use a trigger or a stored procedure to be sure to have the number generated correctly without skipped or duplicated numbers, due to concurrent inserts of invoices.

For what I understand, the best approach would be to create a trigger, in the after insert of my invoices table, that does the work in a single transaction.

So I came up with this, that seems to work nice (more tests this weekend)

```
CREATE TRIGGER Invoices_SetInvoiceNum ON Invoices AFTER INSERT
AS 
declare @next int
Begin tran
set nocount on
update counters set @next=InvoiceNum=InvoiceNum+1
update Invoices set InvoiceNum = @next from inserted i join Invoices p on  p.Id = i.Id
IF @@ERROR = 0
COMMIT TRAN
ELSE
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

1. Is this a good approach or there is a better way to be sure that the number will never be duplicated or skipped?
2. It's more safe to use also a table/record lock? if yes could you suggest an integration to my trigger?

Thanks in advance for any insight on this topic.

Comment: I know its too late but want to know whether the above approach worked ?

Comment: This solution is still in production without problems

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Is it necessary to use transaction inside triggers?I think triggers will automatically rollback transaction if any transaction failed.

Comment: Yep, if it is in autocommit there is an implicit begin transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be make the invoice column a [Identity column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) and let it increment itself.

```
CREATE TABLE Invoices
(
 InvoiceNum int IDENTITY(1,1),
 AccountNum int,
 OtherStuff varchar(30)
);
```

See [this runnable example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/120083/example-for-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-8360309)

Comment: This is not an option, because for this kind of documents I have to reset the number every fiscal year.

Comment: Do the documents have to start at 1 or can you do somthing like `YY-xxxxx` as the invoice number and set the `YY` to the current year?

Comment: The invoice must be 1, 2,..., n

Comment: You can reset the counter in the column with the command `DBCC CHECKIDENT (Invoices, RESEED, 0)`

Comment: So every year I must send a DB specific command via a webpage (the user must choose when change the fiscal year) and have a composite primary key with year and number. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Correct, one of the steps of the client's "End of Fiscal Year Procedure" would be to click a button to reset the invoice count. It would increment the stored "Year" for new records and execute the `DBCC CHECKIDENT (Invoices, RESEED, 0)` command (Preferably inside a transaction with the table locked).

Comment: I marked as answer to close the topic. Thanks for your point of view, but I think I will stick with my solution for this project, because I need the application to be decoupled from the DB.

Comment: This is not a good implementation if different invoices have different sequence ranges